# Comparing string with array element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, search

I am trying to make a code that will pick a random image from a list and ask the user to try and identify it. So far I can generate the image but have run into trouble trying to compare the string with the array element.

```
var imageArray=new Array()
myImages[1]="image1.jpg"
myImages[2]="image2.jpg"
myImages[3]="image3.jpg"

var randNum=Math.floor(Math.random()*imageArray.length);

function pickImg()
{
if {randNum==0)
{
randNum=1;
}
document.write('<img src="'+imageArray[randNum]+'" border=0>');
}

pickImg()

function checkAns()
{
var str = imageArray[randNum];
var n = str.search('textBox');
if(n = -1)
{
alert{"Wrong Answer")
}
Else
{
alert("Right Answer")
}
}
```

I am at a loss when it comes to the second function and comparing the two strings. Thank you for any help.

Comment: ...also should be `else`, not `Else`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov damn, 
there are too many...

Comment: Lots of mistakes going on there... I'd suggest you start learning JS from scratch _the right way_. You can begin here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript

Comment: Maybe i should revert the editing, it's kinda answering his question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your input has ID `textBox`, you should use:

```
var check = str.indexOf(document.getElementById('textBox').value);
if(check == -1)
{
...
```

- `search` expects a regular expression object as an argument, not a string
- The `=` operator *assigns* values, whereas the `==` operator *compares* values
- JS is case sensitive: you're looking for `else`, not `Else`
- Indentation is very important for maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your code

```
if(n = -1)//Assigns -1 as the value of 'n'(Used assignment operator here)
{
   alert{"Wrong Answer")
}
Else
{
   alert("Right Answer")
}
```

Try to change the code to

```
if(n == -1)//Checking whether the value of 'n' is -1 or not(comparison)
{
    alert("Wrong Answer")
}
else
{
   alert("Right Answer")
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain assignment and comparison. =)

Comment: there is one more syntax error in your code. `alert{`

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! I am trying to match user input with part of an array element to make a simple memorization game. The page will then display if the entry was correct or incorrect.